# How to create a user specific function with a built-in function name?

Tags: derby

Can we create an sql function with the name of a [built in derby function](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/ref/rrefsqlj29026.html)?

For example, I need to create a function that replaces [SUBSTR](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/ref/rrefsqlj93082.html).

I am working with the Derby Embedded database and I need to do this with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUBSTR is a built in function and a [reserved keyword](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/ref/rrefkeywords29722.html) in derby.

You won't be able to replace that out of the box. Derby doesn't support functions with the same name and different method signatures.

You could download the [sources](https://db.apache.org/derby/dev/derby_source.html), change the relevant function definition and compile your own version of derby.

Comment: But I can able to override TO_DATE in derby. Why I can't SUBSTR?

Comment: This is because of TO_DATE is not a reserved keyword in derby?

Comment: TO_DATE is not a [built in derby function](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/ref/rrefsqlj29026.html), therefore you can define it yourself.